# Trying to make simple calculator

Tags: python, calculator

```
val = float(input("Division(1) eller multiplikation(2)"))
if val == 1:


div1 = float(input('Ange din täljare: '))
div2 = float(input('Ange din nämnare: '))
print(div1 / div2)

elif val == 2:

mult1 = float(input('Ange din faktor: '))
mult2 = float(input('Ange din andra faktor: '))
print(mult1 * mult2)


input()
```

im trying to make a calculator and it works until i put in the if code. It says expected an indented block.

Comment: Format your code. Especially in a language like Python, and when you're getting indentation errors, unformatted code is nearly useless. I'd fix it, but I don't want to make any assumptions about your indentation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check out this article to help you ask better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Some languages (C,Java,C#) use brackets for form code blocks. Python uses indentation. Try this:

```
val = float(input("Division(1) eller multiplikation(2)"))
if val == 1: 
    div1 = float(input('Ange din täljare: '))
    div2 = float(input('Ange din nämnare: '))
    print(div1 / div2)

elif val == 2: 
    mult1 = float(input('Ange din faktor: '))
    mult2 = float(input('Ange din andra faktor: '))   
    print(mult1 * mult2)


input()
```

Make sure you do not mix tabs and spaces for indentation as python might not be able to understand that 4 spaces equals one tab-character and gives you errors.